# Can't install mongodb on debian 10 using official instructions

Tags: linux, debian, mongodb

Following the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

returns

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I removed an earlier version of mongodb using purge because the service wouldn't start, but now i can't reinstall it. 
Trying to manually install dependencies i get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I think that it is not a clean installation of Debian. What have you done before you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Per the install guide you are following, MongoDB 4.2.0 only has binary packages available for Debian 9 “Stretch”.

Official packages for Debian 10 ([SERVER-37768](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37768)) will be available starting from the upcoming MongoDB 4.2.1 release.

Server & driver releases are announced in the [mongodb-announce](https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-announce) Google Group; there will be at least one Release Candidate (RC) before 4.2.1 ships.

> mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not going to be installed

Due to `libcurl` dependency conflicts in Debian 10 (`libcurl3` and `libcurl4` both provide `libcurl.so.4`), Debian 9 packages are not compatible. Debian 9 used `libcurl3`; Debian 10 packages use `libcurl4`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently libcurl3 and libcurl4 cannot coexist. Issue was resolved after i removed libcurl4

Comment: I removed libcurl 4 but `Package 'libcurl3' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 0):

Use the official source list from Mongodb for Debian 9 Stretch using the following command.

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/4.2 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list

The official MongoDB documentation is confusing.